# Editing an imported SASS file is not updating page in Chrome DevTools

Tags: sass, google-chrome-devtools, gulp-sourcemaps

Like many developers I am using SASS as a preprocessor. I want to edit my stylesheets in Chrome. I've setup **Source Maps** to do this, and I know Chrome now supports SASS.

I have a SASS file, `style.scss`, used to create `style.css` used on the page. It's mainly just imports of other SASS files. Eg:

```
@import "colors";
```

Clicking an imported SASS file, like `_colors.scss`, it shows a green 'active' icon and shows it is linked to a source map.

However when I edit a SASS variable - like the `$dark-blue` in the screenshot below, where I've made it a red instead - the file doesn't change, nor does the page update.

[image]

**How do I edit an imported SASS file in Chrome DevTools?**

**Edit**: note the 'Linked to' on the imported file doesn't seem correct. The only way `_colors.scss` is used is part of `style.scss` which is turned into `style.css`. I suspect this is the cause of the problem. I've opened https://github.com/gulp-sourcemaps/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/349 to see if this is the case.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to edit it from the Sources panel (which is the correct way to do it), so this should work. Any chance you can reduce this to a minimal example so that we can reproduce?

Comment: @KayceBasques I think the issue may actually be with gulp-sass / gulp-sourcemaps - which made the `import`ed file point to an incorrect sourcemap - rather than Chrome. See https://github.com/gulp-sourcemaps/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/349

Comment: Someone else’s problem... the best kind! Ping me here if it ends up being something on our end (the DevTools team).